# ContourPlot3D in a Cube region creates just an opaque cube

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions

I tried the following code

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z} \[Element] Cube[2], RegionBoundaryStyle -> None]
```

And I got only this opaque cube. So I cannot see the contour surface I am trying to plot. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: The `Element region` is a new feature,maybe a bug.  `ContourPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, f = True], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> Automatic]`

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks. But I am trying to make `{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}` a little bit shorter.

Comment: Please report this to Support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug! We can compare with the follwing two result.

```
       GraphicsGrid[{{ContourPlot3D[
    x y z, {x, y, z} ∈ 
     ImplicitRegion[x + y <= 1 , {x, y, z}], 
    RegionBoundaryStyle -> Opacity[0.1], ContourStyle -> Green, 
    Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 50],
   ContourPlot3D[
    x y z, {x, y, z} ∈ 
     ImplicitRegion[-1 <= x <= 1 , {x, y, z}], 
    RegionBoundaryStyle -> Opacity[0.1], ContourStyle -> Green, 
    Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 50]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: So, to be clear, you were able to workaround the bug by using `GraphicsGrid`? Have you found any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version
```

> 13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z} ∈ Cube[2], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full]
```

> [image: sphere]